# a confuse about jquery live() method parameter

Tags: jquery, live

suppose I have a nomal function:

```
    function begin(e) {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);
    }
```

I want the same function could appear in one element's live function:

```
    $('img.clone').live('click', function (e) {
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'copy';
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text', this.id);
    })
```

situation1:the firebug would say the e.dataTransfer is undefined?
however,if I change to this :

```
$('img.clone').live('click', function () {
       begin(e);
})
```

this could not doesn't work ,it also says e.dataTransfer is undefined,

but if I use it in addEventListener('dragstart', begin, false),this could work?

So how can I pass the "e" correctly in live() method?

Comment: What is `dataTransfer` and where does it come from?

Comment: Protip: use [`$.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of live. You need jQuery 1.7+. The jQuery docs advise against using `$.live()` and favour `$.on()` or `$.delegate()` instead.

Comment: .live is deprecated use [on][1] : 

    $('img.clone').on("click", function(event){
     // Your code
    });


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`e.dataTransfer` is undefined not `e`.

Try

`e.originalEvent.dataTransfer`...

jQuery stores the original event in `e.originalEvent`, the `e` itself is not a real event object but a normal object that jQuery created.

Answer (score 1):

`$('img.clone').live('click', function (e) {` is correct. If it doesn't work the issue is somewhere else.

Probably you need to use `e.originalEvent` instead of `e` to access the `dataTransfer` property.

Comment: sorry,it's the e.dataTransfer is undefined

Comment: Use `e.originalEvent.dataTransfer`

Answer (score 1):

That is because `this` keyword inside your `begin` function belongs to `window` object and not  `img.clone`.

Also you are not passing `e`:

```
$('img.clone').live('click', function () {
       begin(e);
})
```

Should be:

```
$('img.clone').live('click', function (e) {
       begin(e);
})
```

BTW, `live` is deprecated, consider using [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler instead.